# Configuring HTTP Redirection for Workflows in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to redirect to a third party entity from api store after user subscribes for an api by following WSO2 documentation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+HTTP+Redirection+for+Workflows. 
but after user subscribe to an api it's not redirecting to thirt party url. and also i'm not getting any logs in console.

Comment: did you enable the enable the workflow executor in  /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml (remove the default one related to <SubscriptionCreation> . Cannot have both)

Comment: it worked. the problem was with the java versions. i had compiled jar in different java version than  servers java version.